# OMP accelerate the c++ dll but slow down the Unity

Tags: c++, performance, unity-game-engine, dll, openmp

I writed a c++ native dll with heavy maths computation, and then put it into Unity engine to run.

The problem is that:
When I used OMP in c++, the OMP did improve the c++'s performance, which I measured by logging out the time. But OMP would slow down the Unity. Unity would run faster if I removed the OMP.

So, how could OMP boosted the dll and slowed down the Unity at the meantime?

Here is what the omp does:

```
DLLEXPORT void UpdateTreeQuick(DbvtWrapper* wrapper, Vector3* prePositions, Vector3* positions, Triangle* triangles,
    int triangleCount, float margin)
{
    bool needPropagate = false;
    double d1 = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for (int i = 0; i < triangleCount; i++)
    {
        Vector3 sixPos[6];
        sixPos[0] = prePositions[triangles[i].A];
        sixPos[1] = prePositions[triangles[i].B];
        sixPos[2] = prePositions[triangles[i].C];
        sixPos[3] = positions[triangles[i].A];
        sixPos[4] = positions[triangles[i].B];
        sixPos[5] = positions[triangles[i].C];
        DbvtVolume vol = DbvtVolume::FromPoints(sixPos, 6);
        if (wrapper->m_dbvt->refit(wrapper->m_leaves[i], vol, margin))
            needPropagate = true;
    }

    double d2 = omp_get_wtime();
    if (triangleCount == 10222)
        Debug::Log(d2 - d1);
}
```

Here is how I call this native code in Unity:

```
private void Update()
{
    NativeAPI.UpdateTreeQuick(nativeDvbtWrapper, (Vector4*)nativePrePositionsWorld.GetUnsafePtr<Vector4>(),
        (Vector4*)nativePositionsWorld.GetUnsafePtr<Vector4>(), (Triangle*)nativeTriangles.GetUnsafePtr<Triangle>(),
        m_mesh.triangles.Length / 3, m_aabbMargin);
}
```

Wit OMP, 2 threads: the c++ code run with a time cost of 7-05 second, the Unity 125-130FPS;
Without OMP: c++ cost 0.0002008 seconds, BUT the Unity run at 138 FPS!

So,Again, how could OMP boosted the dll while slowed down the Unity at the meantime?

Comment: How is your DLL connected to Unity? How often do you call into the DLL and do those calls directly start multithreaded tasks?

Answer (score 0):

> So, how could OMP boosted the dll and slowed down the Unity at the meantime?

More details would be great here, but:
In doubt, this can depend on many aspects. Besides the ones mentioned by AlexGeorg:

1. What are these OMP routines doing exactly? Which kinds of OMP-patterns are used? Which OpenMP version is used? Which kind of data is relevant for OpenMP in your runtime context? How "local" are the data sets you operate on?
2. Common OMP usage doesn't ensure a nice "main thread" discharge. Even if you strictly separate master from OMP slave work, that doesn't ensure a fluid main core behavior of your CPU a priori. It further depends on aspects like thread/CPU affinity in doubt.
3. Typical performance droppers for OpenMP-usage cases are cache(!) and sometimes pipeline bottlenecks. Especially if there is a lot of interference with parts of Unity, this might arise.
4. Maybe this has nothing to do with the FPS problem but it might be questionable that you forward pointers (the vectors) to your OMP loop. In doubt this can lead to hidden bottlenecks or even harder problems if not analyzed well enough since you hide the shared state of actual values a bit.
5. What's this refit method doing and is it a static/ const method? I'm not that familiar with Unity. Is there a chance for blocking GPU calls (CUDA)?
6. What you could try further is to measure
   general OpenMP thread pool creation time in the Unity working context (you could use a quite easier task for that). How often is your routine called?
7. You could further look for main thread issues in removing the master thread (id 0) from the work.
8. If nothing helps, try to compare to another parallelization approach via std::thread simply or intel threading building blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your qucik reply, I have added the details, please help me.

Comment: By default all sane OpenMP runtimes will use a thread pool. They may also have threads actively poll while waiting for the next parallel region. That could kill the performance of other threads. So if Unity is already multi-threaded, then by introducing OpenMP you are causing over-subscription, with all of its performance horrors. You may be able to tell the OpenMP threads to go to sleep in the kernel immediately, e.g. by setting the envirable OMP_WAIT_POLICY https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse55.html